# Android BLE notifications packets wrong order

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

For some reason BLE notifications, recived in onCharacteristicChanged, have wrong order. On windows the packet order for the same device and characteristic is proper. Please, help me to find where the problem is.

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(BleConstants.MY_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
       MyData data = MyDataConverter.convertData(characteristic.getValue());
       Log.i("Data", String.valueOf(data.timeStamp));
    }
}
```

the log

```
06-07 18:25:39.931  13488-14238/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15942
06-07 18:25:39.936  13488-14238/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15962
06-07 18:25:39.981  13488-13498/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15746
06-07 18:25:39.986  13488-13498/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15766
06-07 18:25:40.031  13488-13500/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15786
06-07 18:25:40.031  13488-13500/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15806
06-07 18:25:40.076  13488-14060/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15827
06-07 18:25:40.081  13488-14060/com.package.package I/Data﹕ 15847
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that `onCharacteristicChanged` is called concurrently in different threads because Notifications come so fast, and since the time difference between threads is so small, it becomes a matter of chance as to which thread manages to get the lock on the `Log` function first and post the data.

So it's probably the random internal delays that cause the data to appear in different order on the log screen.